# Why am I getting Error: TS2322 even though field value is of corresponding type?

Tags: typescript

I constructed some complex types and now I'm getting error: TS2322.
I guess best is to show you the failing code:

[image]

`ApiCall.type` and `ApiResponse.type` has the same type: `ApiCallType`

`ApiCallType` is enum holding the possible types:

```
enum ApiCallType {
  SET_USERNAME = 'set-username',
  GET_USER = 'get-user'
}
```

Why is this code failing, even though `ApiCall.type` and `ApiResponse.type` are of the same type and `ApiCallType.SET_USERNAME` + `ApiCallType.GET_USER` (all possible options) both work?

Here is picture of the complete error:
[image]

and a link to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=4&pln=12&pc=24#code/PQKj4yunb+ECgAEJno5r3kBUCeADgKYDOAxgE4CWhALnkWSgq2+xzMIosQHYBXALbIAgoWoBhAIYAbWQRLIA3imQBlAKK4A+gFUtAJQByogLKbkAXmQByUsToBaAQ8p9pQ4rYA0agOLa+kbWdgDmji5utogAvjx0TGIShsQAjgJkdIrEZtKEoaroANriUnIKTAB0WroGmibmmgC6AFwqyK7E7p7E7aR0NHxhyPElZTLyOVWBdUZtKvHxiIlKZamkhAD2fA45eQU2RcilEpOVJDVB9Y0WC8pjJxMV07PBDfedbv2D1MPFzVGcQSSVEABMwTkAGLUYiySFbA4AHjMAD5CmpigBpZB-ZAAa2I+C2ADNkGZPqs+sgcbFkAAycnY5rAlZJaGw+GkKGULZCZFojElHF4wnEskU9rKZBU9q01lU5AAST4dG6DnIdGRuB8gqOmJFfAJRNJ5IWuAZTKxLOWipVasoGq1+VIKIAjLqAEzo-XC3FGsWmsxuhY44gADzVfDBpGN4vJnuQAH5yW7mZazJ70+0+MQAG7dBVJPR8ahq7W6n0qA3+uNB83IAA+VptIKUBxL1B2uC2+3ySL0PnJVb0yAjUZjdYlyaZekBOfz3QA3G3iMhOzseXy+4QUVWO6Xu72mMjAxKh2ieH8HSTpOQ1+syNtdsR1AJyPfSLHjqR35-SO0gyZKy17dLe97JNQGzPg4miULylDVug3QIT8QxhEWawpOkmQDDuAAS0ikBycJgqE4KQkwMKkT2yKPhkWQ7qiiDAMAuAAPIACLse05A7KQ1Bgt0yCUMQhCyHefwjAA7mWAAWLHADKoLYQxeEnvkhHEVRnJkTY9rqsQmoHK6JFclu-L9o+mz8cQTFDtZMF2RphDMYq9G4QwNgbnwFk7kiHmMS5WlmWCzFslhUFPrZoWxjYsUWXR2E2S+TERQ+yVOQRRFvh+ZBxcqqqGcZVmZbZuX-g5ZWpS5bkqVFKUOAcOhwQh7GUDkWkVfloSduWpUNU5rVbJQVWDTFwU5X++V1ZF0G2QcIU6aRojRsNlDtZ1U15V+oQGY6RnOoQrqORNJDUVyY3zS+zXrZtTBddNX6zRl40vr1h6+byQj+adN2aURoWrWCd0dQ923-i9kHnORqmeU2kHXQ4PAsZwaPoxjEAsDgOM4DkFA0PQjAkLGmjRsgTjIJo4aeOJa6SFsQksJjLOs-A3CIHxuwMKJQhbGqnHSHQ0ihPYfJrrz-NrgAVqQOzIAM6ExFzAzIGCQvSO0zzyKEABS6jscYVSENIB0ABSSwLGvIERCu-MMACUPAqzz0Uvv4-DdNQ5Ba9VDhChgspqxrVRUn4mAoSN7S2Le1CyMQYK+MCLsiW7DjqI4ehuB4Xi+29-u+oHTB5+c0y1O8tyaOHGCR5Q0ex-Hid+PEKeiY1xAe3QWfdHnSNroX6BB9rFzEDM1xGNXyHwVHdgNwnSexEAA)

### Further Explanation

I'm developing a websocket API. Both sites server and client should be able to use the types. I'm not so familiar with typescript. This is my approach to describe the data I wanna send. If a websocket message arrives, I consider its data to be an `ApiCall` which is `ApiRequest` or `ApiResponse`.

I can distinguish them by a **success** or **error** field, which indicates that it has to be an `ApiResponse`.

Both `ApiRequest` and `ApiResponse` have the following fields:

- type -> ApiCallType
- definitions regarding to its `ApiCallType`

I can define each CallType like this:

```
type ApiRequestTypeMap = {
  [ApiCallType.SET_USERNAME]: { username: string }
  [ApiCallType.GET_USER]: {}
}
```

### Summary

| Important Types | description |
| --- | --- |
| ApiCallType | enum describing possible Response/Request types |
| ApiCall | `ApiResponse` or `ApiRquest` |
| ApiRequest | participant who initiates an communication is sending an request |
| ApiResponse | reaction to request |
| ApiResponseTypeMap | holds definitions for each ResponseType |
| ApiRquestTypeMap | holds definitions for each RequestType |
| ApiResponseSuccess | `success: true` |
| ApiResponseError | `error: string` |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really helps to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue with as little code as possible.  In your case, the problem is this:

```
type Union = { k: 1, v: string } | { k: 2, v: string } | { k: 1, z: number };
const u: Union = { k: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2, v: "" }; // error!
//    ~
// Type '{ k: 1 | 2; v: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Union'.
```

Here we have a type named `Union` and a value named `u` whose type is something like `{k: 1 | 2, v: string}`.  It seems obvious to a human being that `u` must either be a value of type `{k: 1, v: string}` or `{k: 2, v: string}` and thus assignable to `Union`.  That is, as human beings, we naturally imagine *propagating* the union from the property up to the object itself.  But the compiler *does not do this* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#8289](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289)). The type `{k: 1|2, v: string}` is not assignable to any single constituent of the `Union` union, and so the assignment fails.  That's the full explanation...

---

...or, rather, that *was* the full explanation prior to TypeScript 3.5's introduction of [smarter union type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779).  Now, there *are* times where unions are propagated up from properties.  Here's a minor modification which makes things work in TypeScript 3.5+:

```
type Vnion = { k: 1, v: string } | { k: 2, v: string }; // removed { k: 1, z: number }
const v: Vnion = { k: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2, v: "" }; // okay
```

It might be surprising that merely by removing `{k: 1, z: number}` from the union type would make the assignment to `Vnion` work, especially because `{k: 1, z: number}` did not enter into our mental model of why the assignment to `Union` failed.

The answer for why this matters is a bit involved, but can be found in the notes for microsoft/TypeScript#30779:

> For each matching constituent of 'target', we relate the remaining non-discriminant properties of 'source' to 'target'. If any remaining properties are not related, we determine 'source' is not related to 'target'.

In the case here, 'source' has been expanded from `{k: 1|2, v: string}` to `{k: 1, v: string} | {k: 2, v: string}` and 'target' is `Union`, which is `{ k: 1, v: string } | { k: 2, v: string } | { k: 1, z: number }`.  Since `k`, the [discriminant property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#tagged-union-types), is present in `{k:1, z:number}`, the compiler checks the "non-discriminant" property of `source`, `v`, against `{k:1, z:number}`.  It isn't related, and so the whole assignment fails.

I don't fully understand *why* this check happens; presumably leaving it out would allow some spurious or unexpected assignments to take place.  But it has the effect of blocking the sort of assignment you're doing, unfortunately.

And *that* is (closer to) the full explanation.

---

So what can you do about it?  Well, as in all cases where you know more about the type of some value than the compiler does, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler not to worry so much and that you have taken care of verifying type safety here:

```
const w = { k: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2, v: "" } as Union; // okay
```

That's probably what I'd recommend, since it changes your code the least.

Another workaround is to refactor the value you're assigning so that it starts off life as a union instead of an object whose property is a union:

```
const x: Union = { ...Math.random() < 0.5 ? { k: 1 } : { k: 2 }, v: "" }; // okay
```

That works because you've got a value of type `{k: 1} | {k: 2}` instead of `{k: 1 | 2}`.

Finally, you *could* make a function that does nothing at runtime, but gives the compiler explicit instructions to propagate a union from a single property up to the top:

```
const y: Union = expandProperty({ k: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2, v: "" }, "k")
```

This is possible but then you need to maintain and explain the `expandProperty()` function, which might look like this:

```
type ExpandProperty<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K] = T[K]> =
    V extends any ? { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? V : T[P] } : never;

const expandProperty = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, k: K) => 
  obj as ExpandProperty<T, K>;
```

So I'd only recommend this in case you find yourself running into this union-propagation issue often and don't want to have to either assert your way out each time or refactor your code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigbygawFxQCMANFAG4EDOwATgnAOZQC+UAPlrgQEykVTU6jFu074ipAF4E4AVwC2AIwg0WAbgBQAYxTUosgvGSoM2cQFkAhsAAWAOhqW4AEyTyAFAEooAHigAGOwBWKAB+IigePgIAIhj1KAB6RKgVGiQaAEINZKg8qAA-HJSAFXBoAHIzAkJRbjVyKlp6BgbmCqgESig4JGAoS0pKBAY4S0UAG2hgJChQSCgKoxQKuw11+egANUQUdDEa6IFm4VYOaqheRuOhJlZcmgh5JDIIZzmbLoIAWm+APlEFxIUGkPQUylUzE0Ojgen4O2M+wuVlsDicrg83j8gRC4VqUWucQSuSQOEsIHW6xhegA7kiuFAUfZHC43F5fAFgmEIgT+ETWINYLs4A0SWSKVTdP0AB6GYX0uyKplo1mYjk47lAkQEC7cFhHfmilKk8mUjSbKAAUWlYHRAAV0pAaKAfCVSABpVLS4AQFzdHAQEBIABmUDdUC2Xp9frDAG13QBdfYleMJgFoDT5CNR33ObpOECaqCxu2dVABoOhkoJgiliDe3PdT3hSMEFN2pOsGQQV40TTaKVe20uB1IJ2gfauj05mMVkNhv7uJCKABWbdI4nd3jQAOXK4G3Wtw+co-HICnUHdf2hg5AcsRGHrx9PKlA7mR1mZ6LZWM5uJ5lwGvEzCkDEOAxJ4GhAA)

Comment: Wow! Very thank you for this detailed answer. I learned so much from it!
And sorry for not making the code example smaller. But I couldn't exactly locate the problem.

Comment: So I've solved my problem. I extended my union for each branch with the type of my enum. Let's say I have `enum Numbers {ONE = 'one', TWO = 'two'}` and `type Union = { k: Numbers.ONE, v: string } | { k: Numbers.TWO, v: string }`. To fix the issue you need to add `{ k: Numbers, v: string }` to Union